# Drupal: Programmatically saving imagefield images

Tags: php, image, drupal, cck, synchronization

I'm trying to write a sync function that saves some data to nodes, which works fine, until I try to save the thumbnail image associated with the node.

I've managed to download the file and put it in my sites/default/files folder, but what's the best way to tell Drupal, "put this file in that CCK imagefield"?

**EDIT
To clarify a bit.. I sync the thumbnails separately (since one image can be used by several nodes)... I would like the initial thumbnail sync to save the files in the correct folder (not a temp one) and just point the imagefield to this file... That's what annoys me with field_file_save_file(), it saves a new file instead of just making a pointer..
Any advice?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kinda solved this myself I think. I field_file_save_file() my thumbnails separately and then field_file_load() them when syncing the nodes.

Seems to be working alright. :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use `field_file_save_file();` to move the file from a temp directory to your desitnation and create the object to be saved as a CCK field.

See: http://api.lullabot.com/field_file_save_file

Then you can save your field using the returned value like so:

`$node->field_image[0] = field_file_save_file($my_file_path, array(), $my_destination);`

You'll probably need to run a few tests. So you'll need to trash your destination directory and do it again.

Answer (score 5):

This code will do it:

```
$imagefile = '/temp/somefile.jpg';
// Load up the CCK field  
$field = content_fields('field_image', 'mycontenttype');
// Load up the appropriate validators
$validators = array_merge(filefield_widget_upload_validators($field), imagefield_widget_upload_validators($field));
// Where do we store the files?
$files_path = filefield_widget_file_path($field);
// Create the file object, replace existing file with new file as source and dest are the same
$file = field_file_save_file($imagefile, $validators, $files_path, FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE);


$node = node_load($mynode);
$node->field_image[] = $file;
$node = node_submit($node);
node_save($node);
```

Comment: Cool! I had something similar laid out, but without node_submit().. What's the diff?

Comment: node_submit creates the teaser, adds user if not set and sets creation date and update date for the node.

Comment: Work'd like a charm. I was just passing in empty promises (null) for validators and FILE_EXISTS_REPLACE - your example is a great pattern for this task. I'll reference it again for sure ;)

Answer (score -4):

You will need to poke around in the database. 
Unfortunately, your database can be layed out in numerous ways, acc to the use of fields. So explaining is a little hard. CCK will move around tables, rename stuff, and (de) normalise databases if it thinks this is needed. The data may be anywhere :) And depending on where it lives now, it becomes easier or harder to fix this problem.

Say, your node type is **foo** and the thumbnail field is **bar**. You could have a column **bar** in the table **content_foo**, but you could also have a table **content_field_bar**

Inside that table, the imagefield stores foreign keys to the **file** table. You either need to find the entry in the file table, if it exists, or else enter a new record. This is not easy. Then add the key for that file entry in the content_foo table, column bar, or in content_field_bar.

But, before starting with this: it really is not worth the pain: just delete the node and copy-paste the content in a new one.

Comment: Noooooo! don't poke around in the database!

Comment: sure. But if your database is broken, you will need to poke arount in it to fix it again. And Aces Database seems broken.

Comment: Very bad advice ... never touch the database directly.

Comment: Why is that bad? If your database is broken, you will need to dive into the Database. Period. 
But aside: why would it be bad to touch the database directly?

Comment: Because when you advise people to poke around in the database, they are more likely to end up with a broken database which needs more poking. And then you have unleashed the river of pokery on them too. And we will send them to your house to ask why they are poked.

Comment: I RARELY EVER have to go into the database - and if you do find yourself diving into the database, do some more googling because I bet your going about things a little backwards :) no offense, thats just been my experience.